# How to handle popup windows in Geckofx

Tags: c#, popup, geckofx

I don't know how I can handle popup windows in Gekofx. When the popup appear i must click on a button from this popup window.
I tried to make this with the CreateWindow event, but I can't make it work.

```
GeckoElementCollection followamf = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement item in followamf)
        {
            string aux = item.GetAttribute("class");
            if (aux != null && aux != "" && aux.Equals("single_like_button btn3-wrap"))
            {
                webBrowser.CreateWindow += webBrowser_CreateWindow;
                item.Click();
                break;

            }
        }
void webBrowser_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
    {

         //This code doesn't work, because is search in main browser not in the popup and
    // I want to search in the popup. 
        GeckoElementCollection followtwitter = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement item in followtwitter)
        {
            string aux = item.GetAttribute("class");
            if (aux != null && aux != "" && aux.Equals("button"))
            {

                item.Click();
                break;

            }
        }
    }
```

If someone can help me I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code the `webBrowser` variable is global so your `webBrowser_CreateWindow` function is searching in the original browser.

The `GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs` argument in `webBrowser_CreateWindow` contains a `WebBrowser` property that you can set to be a new instance of `GeckoWebBrowser`. After the event handler returns, the instance of `GeckoWebBrowser` that you provided to the `GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs` will have the popup document loaded in it. You should save a reference to the new `GeckoWebBrowser`, add a handler for it's `DocumentCompleted` event, and then check it for the element you want to click.

Also, you should only add the `CreateWindow` event handler once, otherwise it will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
gecko.CreateWindow += Gecko_CreateWindow;
private void Gecko_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.WebBrowser.Window.IsTopWindow())
            {
                 //your code here
                 //e.Cancel = true;//If you want to block popups
            }
    }
```